# Remove console logs from selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, logging, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I've tried a few things but I can never get rid of all the console logs. The most I could get is this:

[image]

I'm using the selenium webDriver and PhantomJs.
How can I remove the last logs remaining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, logging could be implemented using different libraries and each one of them should be controlled separately. It seems that PhantomJS is using `java.util.logging` so you can try doing:

```
LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
```

This should switch off all logging that comes from `java.util.logging`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using desired capabilities:

```
new PhantomJSDriver(
  new DesiredCapabilities().setCapability(
    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS,
    new String[]{"--webdriver-loglevel=NONE"}));
```